# Select rows using having > 1 same column 1 but other column 2

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table rows like this:

```
NAME    SIZE    ARTICLE
aaa     S       1
aaa     M       1
aaa     L       1
aaa     XL      1
bbb     S       2
bbb     M       2
bbb     L       2
ccc     S       3
ccc     M       3
ccc     L       3
ddd     S       4
ddd     M       4
ddd     L       4
```

Those rows are OK. But lets have another rows like this:

```
eee     S       2
eee     XXL     2
```

And this is the problem, because this article has `ARTICLE = 2`, but its already used by `NAME = bbb`.

I want to select all ARTICLE, where there are under same ARTICLE number different NAME (here `bbb` and `eee`), so that select will here return row data with `2`.

I tried this, but its not working, it will return all rows:

```
SELECT NAME, ARTICLE, COUNT(NAME) FROM products GROUP BY ARTICLE, NAME HAVING COUNT(NAME) > 1
```

Maybe there is some way to do it with `DISTINCT`. Could somebody help me?

Comment: can you provide expecting result..

Comment: As I wrote in the question, in this case it will return ARTICLE number `2`.

Comment: please show in table format what you expect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `exists` for getting the desired result, something as

```
select
distinct p1.name,p1.article from products p1
where 
exists(
  select 1 from products p2 
  where p2.article = p1.article
  and p2.name <> p1.name
)
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/55ad8/2

Answer (score 2):

Yeah you are right you can use DISTINCT

```
SELECT ARTICLE, COUNT(DISTINCT NAME)
          FROM products 
          GROUP BY ARTICLE 
          HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT NAME) > 1
```

This will return the articles which have a more than one different name.

```
| article | COUNT(DISTINCT NAME) |
| 2       |  2                   |
```

To get the names which are corresponds to the article number you can use 
a query like this:

```
SELECT name FROM products
JOIN (SELECT ARTICLE, COUNT(DISTINCT NAME)
      FROM products 
      GROUP BY ARTICLE 
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT NAME) > 1) as sameArticles
ON sameArticles.ARTICLE = products.ARTICLE
GROUP BY name
```

The output is the following:

```
| name|
| bbb |
| eee |
```